# pgfplots: tick marks on axis with fill between

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am plotting a graph and shading some area beneath it using `fill between` like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xmin = 0,
xmax = 7,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 30]
\addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:6] {x^2};
\path[name path=B]
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot[lightgray] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:5}];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

In the example, the tick marks of the x axis are hidden behind the filled area, so I use the usual `axis on top`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xmin = 0,
xmax = 7,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 30,
axis on top]
\addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:6] {x^2};
\path[name path=B]
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot[lightgray] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:5}];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This brings the tick marks to the front as desired but also has a side effect:

[image]

Note that the tick marks in the second picture are placed above the axis:

[image]

I only get this behavior when using `axis on top` together with `fill between`. How can I get the tick marks to be drawn above the fill, but still under the axes?

Comment: Have you seen the `set layers` functionality in the manual?

Comment: how about `every x tick/.style={black},
every y tick/.style={black},
` does that get you closer to what you want?

Comment: @cmhughes That would still draw a black tick on top of the blue circle at `0,0`, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating to PGFPlots v1.14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### New answer

The behavior you observed was considered a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/104/) which is now fixed with the release of v1.14 of PGFPlots. TeXing your `axis on top` example now gives this (hopefully desired) result.

[image: image showing the result of <code>axis on top</code> example]

### Old answer

As percusse has stated in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290702/pgfplots-tick-marks-on-axis-with-fill-between#comment703587_290702) you can use the `set layers` feature and move the filled are to any layer you like. Here an example where you can play a bit what happens, when you change the layer with the resulting image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        fill between/on layer={
%            axis background    % grid and ticks will be above filled area
            axis grid           % only ticks will be above filled area
%            axis ticks         % grid and ticks will be below filled area
%            pre main           % <-- initial value
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=30,
            grid=major,
        ]
            \addplot+[name path=A,domain=0:6] {x^2};
            \path[name path=B]
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
            \addplot[red!10] fill between
                [of=A and B, soft clip={domain=1:5}];

            \coordinate (point to spy) at (1,0);
            \coordinate (show magnification) at (2,20);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

Usually this should not happen. From the documentation on page 381 about `axis on top`:

> Please note that this feature does not affect plot marks. I think it
>   looks unfamiliar if plot marks are crossed by axis descriptions.

So there seems to be a bug in the `fillbetween` library. As a workaround you could **not** use it and instead create the filling differently.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin = 0,
xmax = 7,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 30,
axis on top]
\addplot[fill, lightgray, domain=1:5] {x^2} \closedcycle;
\addplot+[domain=0:6] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: plot]

Comment: It is a bug for sure, because the plot marks are shown correct, when you add `axis on top` to the code in the question and comment the `\addplot fill between` line. (For the record: This relates to PGFPlots v1.13.)